# string indices must be integers Python 3.6.x

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a python program for exact a Facebook public page posts using Facebook graph APi.This code is working when I give the page ID manually but there is a error when I give the Group IDs using text file.There are any one can help me to solve this "string indices must be integers" error.

Error:
line 31, in scrapeGroupPost
    jsonData = data["data"]

TypeError: string indices must be integers

CODE:

with open('groupID.txt') as file:

```
for line in file:    
  graph = GraphAPI('access token here')
  pageID = str(line)
  graph.get(pageID+'/posts')
  txtFile=pageID+'.txt'
  data = graph.get(pageID+'/posts')
  jsonData = data["data"]

  for _ in range(10):
      try:
          url = urllib.request.urlopen(data["paging"]["next"])
          responseData = json.loads(url.read().decode())
          jsonData += responseData["data"]
          data = responseData
      except KeyError:
          break
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with a proper traceback - what exactly throws that error? What debugging have you done to narrow it down?

Comment: I'd also be quite surprised if the graphapi library didn't offer a cursor that enables you to just go through pages without the whole getting the next url, opening it and json loading it yourself...

Comment: Also - I'm assuming `pageID = srt(line)` is supposed to be `pageID = str(line)` otherwise your code wouldn't even get to that point...

Comment: yes...it should be psgeID = str(line). actually problem is occurring when i try to give the page ids using the text file. Otherwise this code was working properly.But I want to get posts data from several pages.therefore I want to automate this code to get the post data from several pages.So are there any way to do this?